# In RavenDB can I retrieve all document Id's for a document type

Tags: ravendb

My Scenario:
I have a few thousand documents that I want alter (rename & add properties), I have written a a PatchRequest to alter the document but this takes a document Id.

I'm looking for a way to get a list of document Id's for all documents of a specific type, any ideas?

If possible I'd like to avoid retrieving the document from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have written a PatchRequest to alter the document but this takes a document Id.

No, .Patch takes a document ID, not the PatchRequest.

Since you want to update a whole swath of documents, you'll want to use the .UpdateByIndex method:

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("IndexName",
      new IndexQuery {Query = "Title:RavenDB"},
      new []
      {
         new PatchRequest
         {
            Type = PatchCommandType.Add,
            Name = "Comments",
            Value = "New automatic comment we added programmatically"
         }
      }, allowStale: false);
```

This will allow you to patch all documents matching an index. That index can be whatever you please.

For more information, see [Set-Based Operations](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/set-based-operations) in the Raven docs.